# android-getting error out of memory with showing images

Tags: android, memory, imageview

I've an imageview that shows an image everytime user run the app . the images are in drawable folder .
every so often the app crash and in the lof cat it says java.lang.outOfMemmoryError

I've lots of images, about 100 images. 100,000 Byet .

What is the solution to show these images to don't use lot of memory ?

thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix OutOfMemory you should do something like that:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

This inSampleSize option reduces memory consumption.

Here's a complete method. First it reads image size without decoding the content itself. Then it finds the best inSampleSize value, it should be a power of 2. And finally the image is decoded.

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
try {
    //Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

    //The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale=1;
    while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale*=2;

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize=scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
 return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, another question . I use a custom listView that shows images too . Should I do something similar and  then show the images in the listView ?